# round corner image in PageView.builder | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to round the corners of the image and bring it to left ( line to start popular music)

What I do, - I used two methods, but they didn't work. codes below the image

[image]

---

code part : (1st try here)

```
Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 180,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8),
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 180,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          // color: Colors.red
                          // image: DecorationImage(
                          //   image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/just.jpg"),
                          // ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            )
```

### This code (1st try) working when I use color in BoxDecoration, when I add image property it not working.  (round corners)

2nd try here

```
Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 180,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8),
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 180,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            child: Image(
                              image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/just.jpg"),
                            )),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            )
```

Comment: second try didn't work? 1st comment parts working here

Comment: Didn't work.
 It also has 0 radius corner. square

Comment: I am using fit property

Comment: it worked.
 fit: BoxFit.cover,
thank you

Comment: and I want to bring it to left ( line to start popular music)

Comment: For 1st pageView item? use `padEnds: false,` on PageView

Comment: yes. it should start below the "P" letter in Popular music

Comment: it worked. Thank you very much. Hv a nice day

Comment: Glad to help, more about [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to include `fit: BoxFit.cover`.

For method one

```dart
 Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 180,
  child: PageView.builder(
      controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8),
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          child: Container(
            height: 180,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              color: Colors.red,
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/just.jpg"), 
                  fit: BoxFit.fill), 
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
)
```